# What does it mean "From what could only have"?

Tags: prepositions, what, could

I saw this sentence, and am wondering what does it mean.

> I also found a shard of glass from what could only have been a
>   Heineken

Comment: In what commonly available references might one look for an answer, and what might be the search term?

Comment: I came here to ask because I couldn't find it in google. so there is no research. so put on hold as off-topic is unfair.

Comment: search term is "from what could only have been". I still didn't get what it means exactly.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you.  I don't know how to search for the answer.  What I know is that "what could only have been X" is the object of the preposition from.  It's a noun phrase.  Think of "what looked like a cat" or "what seemed to have fallen off a car."

Answer (score 2):

It means that the shard of glass could not conceivably have come from anything other than a Heineken (bottle) - i.e. the author is convinced the shard originated from a shattered Heineken bottle. As to why he/she was so convinced, you have to look at the context.